# Apache CXF headers needed inside soap web service

Tags: web-services, cxf

We are having a apache cxf web service. I wrote an inInterceptor which logs the headers to the console.
Our web service has layers like service,serviceImpl......dao
Whre we struck is, we want one of the headers (which is unique for each request) available at DAO.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the current CXF [Message](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Message.html) using [PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/phase/PhaseInterceptorChain.html#getCurrentMessage%28%29).  Once you have the message, you can retrieve the headers just like you would in an Interceptor. For example:

```
Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) message
                .get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
```